# Layout pushes up when keyboard popups

Tags: android, android-layout

Whole layout pushes up when keyboard pops up. Xml file contains listview 
and below that two buttons, when keyboard popups both listview and buttons pushes up.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.athis.buy.HomeScreen">

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#a8b3ff"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Filter"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sort"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Sort"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have added android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" in manifest so that when i touch edittext only then keyboard should pop up

Answer (score 1):

add `windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` attribute in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for that particular `Activity`. refer to this.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Hope this helps. GL!

Comment: So simple solution, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this on your activity on the Manifest

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"